# Onscroll video has to play once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Using scrolltop I divide the scroll into 5 section using if condition.In 2nd section i gave video with scrolltop value from 600 to 700px.The video is playing many times within that position if i scroll again.but I want video has to play once if i any number of times within that value.

```
var scrolld=window.scrollTop();
if(scrolld >=600) {
  ///i gave image here
}

elseif((Scrolld >600) & (scrolld <=700)){
//video
}

//rest 3 elseif contain images
```

check this link:
http://projects.lollypop.biz/auluxa/lighting.html

If i  scrolled using mouse its working fine.But if i scrolled using keyup and keydown(keyboard) video is playing many times.

Comment: give your code what you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at this code. I do think this is what you mean, since i have this on my website aswel, but your question is not very clear. 
Can you atleast share ur code?

```
$('#vid').on('ended', function(){this.playedThrough = true;});

$(window).scroll(function(){
    var myVideo = document.getElementById("vid");

    if($(window).scrollTop() > 300 && $(window).scrollTop() < 975){
       // only if we didn't reached the end yet
       if(!myVideo.playedThrough)
          myVideo.play();
    }else{
       myVideo.pause();
    }
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the currentTime attribute of the video element to check if it is playing before triggering it to play again.

```
var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");
if (vid.currentTime === 0) {
    // Play video...
}
```

Read more [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_prop_currenttime.asp).